# Sharedpreferences to save editText

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to create an app for my own use, and I'm trying to save 3 editText boxes to Sharedpref so I can use those values to calculate things later in the app.

Here's the code:

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private EditText mEditTextBench;
private EditText mEditTextSquat;
private EditText mEditTextDead;
private Button mButton;
public String maxDead =  mSharedPreferences.getString("maxDead", "DEFAULT");
```

Then in the oncreate method I have:

```
mSharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getBaseContext());
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEditTextBench = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBench);
    mEditTextSquat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSquat);
    mEditTextDead = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDead);
```

and my button onclicklistener:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("maxDead", mEditTextDead.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
```

If I put the public String maxDead as a final string in the onCreate method, it works, but I want to be able to change the string in the future, using the editText. I don't think I can put it as a final.

The way the code is now, I get this error:

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: This line
 public String maxDead =  mSharedPreferences.getString("maxDead", "DEFAULT"); should be below:
mSharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getBaseContext());

Comment: are you writing `public String maxDead =  mSharedPreferences.getString("maxDead", "DEFAULT");` outside onCreate?

Comment: @GyanendraMani When i try to put that line String maxDead = mSharedPref..... I get an error saying Variable maxDead accessed from within inner class, must be declared final

Answer (score 1):

your code should be like this.

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private EditText mEditTextBench;
private EditText mEditTextSquat;
private EditText mEditTextDead;
private Button mButton;
public String maxDead;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    mSharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getBaseContext());
    maxDead =  mSharedPreferences.getString("maxDead", "DEFAULT");

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEditTextBench = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBench);
    mEditTextSquat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSquat);
    mEditTextDead = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDead);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("maxDead", mEditTextDead.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT :** here I am showing my way of using `SharedPreference`

```
SharedPreferences myPreference;
String MY_PREFERENCE = "my_preference";
```

inside onCreate initialise `SharedPreference`:

```
myPreference = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

for getting value

```
String data = myPreference.getString("maxDead", "")
```

for editing `SharedPreference` :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPreference.edit();
editor.putString("maxDead", mEditTextDead.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: thanks! Actually I'm still getting an error here when trying to run the program Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: got it to work! made a stupid mistake.. Thanks! One more question, I put a toast message to show what the updated value is, but when I click my button, it works the first time, but then if I change the value and click the button again, it still shows the previous number unless I go out of this layout then back into it. Is there a reason for that? thanks!

Comment: sorry for let comment. can you show me your code where you are printing toast?

Comment: I'm printing toast right after the editor.apply(); in the onClick method

Comment: probably your toast is printing old value of maxDead. what is happening, first you are getting preference data in maxDead, then you are editing preference. and then you are printing maxDead. now maxDead has old value that you assigned earlier. what you can do is after `editor.apply` again get value of preference in maxDead. and then print toast. i am sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because of this :

```
public String maxDead =  mSharedPreferences.getString("maxDead", "DEFAULT");
```

as you've not initialized `mSharedPreferences` so, its throwing `NullPointerException`.

change this to :

```
public String maxDead;
```

and then initialize `maxDead` in your `onCreate` method after you initialize `mSharedPreferences` :

```
maxDead =  mSharedPreferences.getString("maxDead", "DEFAULT");
```

**UPDATE**

You're not getting the updated value of the `maxDead` inside the `onClickListener` as the value of the variable `maxData` is set only once in the `onCreate`. So the variable is not updated when the value of `maxData` is updated in the `SharedPreferences`. So, instead of keeping a variable you should use a method like this to get the latest value from the `SharedPreference` :

```
private String getMaxDead(){
    if(mSharedPreferences == null)
        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getBaseContext());
    return mSharedPreferences.getString("maxDead", "DEFAULT");
}
```

So use : `getMaxDead()` in your toast and it will work.

Comment: thanks! Actually I'm still getting an error here when trying to run the program Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: can you share the complete stacktrace?

Comment: got it to work! made a stupid mistake.. Thanks! One more question, I put a toast message to show what the updated value is, but when I click my button, it works the first time, but then if I change the value and click the button again, it still shows the previous number unless I go out of this layout then back into it. Is there a reason for that? thanks!

Comment: Can't figure out how to post it as code.. but the toast is in the on click listener

Comment: At the end of the onClickListener         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Max deadlift changed to: " + maxDead,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Will let you know soon Ashish thanks, I have a separate error that won't allow me to run the app now lol

Comment: where would I put that string? I tried putting it after the onCreate and before the setOnClickListener, but it didn't work

Comment: which string? i simply said use : `getMaxDead()` wherever you need `maxDead`

Answer (score 0):

I am also very new to Android but I'll try to answer. The reason why you are getting the exception is because when the Activity is created there is nothing in the `String maxDead`, given it is assigned on the top as `private String maxDead`. You only assign a value to it when you click your button. Where do you want to use this value? I can't comment yet, that's why I am writing this in an answer. :(

This is an example of how I use SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences spref = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
editor.putString("maxDead", mEditTextDead.getText().toString());
editor.apply;
```

And then somewhere (another activity/fragment) where you need the value:

```
String maxDead = spref.getString("maxDead", "");
```

Comment: Thanks, what exactly is the double quotes in spref.getString("maxDead, " "); doing? I tried to set an initial value by changing public String maxDead = "100"; instread of public String maxDead.. but still get the error. I need the values in another layout file.

Comment: Got it to work, made a stupid mistake and forgot to delete some of the old code. It actually does work without setting a value to maxDead at the start! :)